# how to focus next cell in kendo grid by enter

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I want to select next cell by pressing enter key in Kendo Grid.
and i'm using following script :

```
 function onDataBound(e) {
        $("#batchgrid").on("focus", "td", function (e) {

            var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
            var cellIndex = $(this).index();
            $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#batchgrid")
                    .data("kendoGrid")
                    .editCell($(".k-grid-content")
                    .find("table").find("tbody")
                    .find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")")
                    .find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")")
                    .next()
                    .focusin($("#batchgrid")
                    .data("kendoGrid")
                    .closeCell($(".k-grid-content")
                    .find("table")
                    .find("tbody")
                    .find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")")
                    .find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")")
                    .parent())));
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

and this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eh8GL/218/). The problem with this code is when I hit enter it will  focus on the next cell but the previous changes won't remain on screen(the last cell will lost the changes somehow).
I know there is a bug with this code I can't figure it out where is the bug.

Comment: I think it's to do with the ordering of the `editCell` and `closeCell` methods in your chain.  Also not sure you need to wrap this in an `onfocus` event?

Comment: Do you have any easier way to do such?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-does-grid-update-its-datasource- In terms of tidying your code a little, have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Eh8GL/221/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [JS FIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/2NrLR/1/)

I have modified the databound event as below.

```
     $("#list").on("focus", "td", function (e) {         
     $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode == 13) {
             setTimeout(function () {
                 var curCell = $("#list").find(".k-state-selected")
                 var eCell = $("#list").find(".k-edit-cell")

                 curCell.removeClass("k-state-selected");
                 curCell.removeClass("k-state-focused");
                 curCell.removeAttr("data-role");
                 curCell.next().addClass("k-state-selected");
                 curCell.next().addClass("k-state-focused");
                 try {                         $('#list').data('kendoGrid').closeCell(eCell);
                 } catch (ex) {
                 }
                 $('#list').data('kendoGrid').select();                     
                 $('#list').data('kendoGrid').editCell(curCell.next());

             }, 50);

         }
     });
 });
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382120/kendo-grid-not-saving-values-after-moving-to-the-next-cell  please see this and help me if you can Thanks

Comment: After a long chase I found this answer, it really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no need to use a databound function, instead you can use a simple and plain keydown or keypress jQuery function.

Have a look at the below code:-

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#batchgrid").keypress(function(e){

var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (keyCode == 13) {
                    var grid = $("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    var curCell = grid.find(".k-edit-cell");
                    grid.editCell(curCell.next()); // To move the cursor to the next cell and put the cell in edit mode
                    grid.select(curCell.next()); // To select the next cell
                    grid.focus(curCell.next()); // To set focus on to next cell   
                    e.preventDefault(); // To prevent the default behavior of the enter key press
                }
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: The var curCell = grid.find(".k-edit-cell"); is invalid. Instead, it should be var curCell = $("#batchGrid").find(".k-edit-cell")

Comment: @Booster- 

The below 2 lines of code:- 
var grid = $("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid");
var curCell = grid.find(".k-edit-cell");  


is equivalent to what you have mentioned in your comment, $("#batchGrid").find(".k-edit-cell").

It doesn't mean that the approach I have mentioned in my answer is invalid, no it's not invalid, just that your code is more optimized.

Comment: @Shivam657 is incorrect. var curCell = grid.find(".k-edit-cell"); throws an exception indicating that object does not support the method "find". I got a similar exception on the grid.focus line. I'm going to submit an edit to this effect.

Comment: After commenting, I actually had an issue when implementing this on an actual grid of kendo having problems when I tried to leave focus on the new object. I will not be submitting an edit after all as I'm not 100% sure my changes would work for everyone generally.

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out the .data("kendogrid") calls in your keydown event you can navigate with tab and edit/close with enter. It looks like you're resetting the data on both focus and blur.

Comment: I did that but when I hit enter after commenting both .data("kendogrid") it doesn't focus on the next cell. do you have any working example?

Comment: why do you want Enter to do that? that's what tab is for!

Comment: That's what customer wants. To be honest the customer is right, as an accountant hitting key strokes 10000 times a day will make the job tiresome if you want to move your wrist. Guess Telerik needs to consider about easy keyboard design.

Comment: 1 enter key or 1 tab key.. still one key press.. if you want enter to switch to next input field, convince all the browser vendors to change that behaviour. The attribute is called tabindex, maybe you can get them to make an enterindex attribute?

Answer (score 1):

this code is work for me

```
$("#grid").on("focus", "td", function (e) {         
    $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                var curCell  = $("#grid").find(".k-edit-cell");

                grid.editCell(curCell.next()); 

            });

        }
    });
});
```

I hope this helps